# Write in descriptive form $B=\{7,12,19,28\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm learning set theory and I got a sheet to complete. Out of 55 questions so far I only have problem with this one and one other.

> Write in descriptive form the following set: $B=\{7,12,19,28\}$.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: $2k^2+k+4$ for $k$ in $\{1,2,3,4\}$

Comment: @DonThousand:  I think you meant $k^2+2k+4$

Comment: How about $B=\{x: x\in \{7,12,19,28\} \}$? Would you be willing to show us what a reasonable answer might look like, and what gives you hesitations about this problem in particular?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes, oops

Comment: What is "descriptive form"? Is that like a verbal description?

Comment: [A few possibilities](https://oeis.org/search?q=7%2C12%2C19%2C28&language=english&go=Search) :-)

Comment: @alex.jordan in the form,i.e., C={x/x∈N&4<x<8}

Comment: @alex.jordan.  Noticethatx/x=1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tabular form is

$B=\{7,12,19,28\}$

Descriptive form is

$B =$ Set of numbers of the form $n$ squared plus two $n$ plus four where $n$ ranges from one to four.

Set Builder form is

$B=\{x:x\in\{7,12,19,28\}\}$

or

$B=\{n:x\in\{1,2,3,4\} ~\wedge~n=x^2+2x+4\}$